# Jest - Mocking a factory function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Function I want to test is `createCarAndDrive()` which uses `Car` module. I'd like to mock one function in the `Car` module so its actual function is not called but the mock function.

So, the `Car` function returns two functions `gas()` and `brake()`. `Car` is implemented by using factory function pattern. So those two functions are wrapped in `Car` and won't be exposed until `Car` is called.

Is it somehow possible to mock the function `brake()` to return `false`?

Here's the implementation.

```js
// Car.js
function Car({ name, model }) {
  function gas(speed) {
    return `${name} ${model} goes forward at a speed of ${speed}km/h`;
  }
  function brake() {
    return true;
  }

  return {
    gas,
    brake,
  };
}

// driver.js
function createCarAndDrive() {
  const car = Car({ name: 'Fiat', model: 'Punto' });
  car.gas(123);
  return car.brake();
}

// driver.test.js
describe('drive', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // How to mock function inside a function?
    jest.mock('./Car', () => ({
      brake: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => false),
    }));
  });

  test('it should not brake', () => {
    const itHitBreak = createCarAndDrive();
    expect(itHitBreak).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jest.mock` factory functions [don't work within test functions](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582).

Move `jest.mock` to the top level scope of your test and it should work:

```
import { createCarAndDrive } from './driver';

jest.mock('./Car', () => ({
  Car: () => ({
    gas: () => 'mock gas',
    brake: () => false
  })
}));

describe('drive', () => {
  test('it should not brake', () => {
    const itHitBreak = createCarAndDrive();
    expect(itHitBreak).toBe(false);  // Success!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mockReturnValue(false)` with jest to force the return value in your tests.

So in your code it will look like something like:

```
...
brake: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false),
...
```

Here is [the `mockReturnValue()` documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values).

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. True is returned. https://imgur.com/a/tDBcZoi